# Erro com credenciais do Google no RStudio

Tags: r, google-drive-api

Eu sou novo em programação em R e estou tentando executar um código R onde acesso o google drive e o google earth engine. No entanto, duas situações estão acontecendo: primeiro no meu laptop pessoal em casa eu executo o código e funciona perfeitamente e nem mesmo abre um navegador para pedir permissão de acesso.
Já no segundo caso, quando utilizo a conexão de desktop remoto e acesso o computador da empresa, o código não consegue obter as credenciais do google.

O que poderia ser? será relacionado ao acesso remoto, à versão do pacote ou outra coisa? segue os dados abaixo :

No meu laptop pessoal:

```
> ## Initialize GEE ----
> ee_Initialize(email = gee_email, drive = TRUE)
-- rgee 1.0.9 ------------------------------------------------------------ earthengine-api 0.1.248 --
 √ email: my.email@colaborator.company.br 
 √ Google Drive credentials:  FOUND
 √ Initializing Google Earth Engine:  DONE!
 √ Earth Engine user: users/rcode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

O mesmo código no computador da empresa por conexão de área de trabalho remota:

```
> ## Initialize GEE ----
> ee_Initialize(email = gee_email, drive = TRUE)
-- rgee 1.0.9 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- earthengine-api 0.1.263 -- 
 √ email: my.email@colaborator.company.br 
 √ Google Drive credentials:Erro: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
  * Read more in: https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
```

depois de executar os comandos:

> options(gargle_quiet = FALSE)

> googledrive::drive_auth("my.email@colaborator.company.br")

```
> trying `token_fetch()`
> trying `credentials_service_account()`
> Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
  Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
> trying `credentials_app_default()`
> trying `credentials_gce()`
> trying `credentials_byo_oauth()`
> Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
  inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
> trying `credentials_user_oauth2()`
> Gargle2.0 initialize
> attempt to access internal gargle data from: googledrive
> adding 'userinfo.email' scope
> loading token from the cache
> no matching token in the cache
> initiating new token
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
> Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
  Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Timed out
Erro: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
  * Read more in: https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
```

Comment: Tenta executar o mesmo código no computador da sua empresa, só que adiciona a linha `options(gargle_quiet = FALSE)`, antes.

Comment: Obrigado, mas não surtiu efeito. Infelizmente o problema persiste. Não sei mais o que fazer. No github também não obtive muito sucesso, o pessoal fica dizendo sempre que o erro é em outro pacote. Assim já passei no gargle, tydiverse, rgee e googledrive e nada.
tidyverse/googledrive/issues/328
r-spatial/rgee/issues/152
r-spatial/rgee/issues/139
r-lib/gargle/issues/177

Comment: quando voce diz "area de trabalho remota", é realmente uma conexao de area de trabalho remota (por exemplo, voce consegue ver a area de trabalho), ou é via SSH?

Comment: Sim, é uma conexão remota pelo aplicativo do windows 10 " Conexão de Área de Trabalho Remota". 
Lá no PC da empresa rodo o RStudio, ele abre o navegador, aceito os passo a passo do login, daí aparece a mensagem para eu retornar a janela do R. Mas dai dá o erro inicial que eu reportei.